# Is the sudden time jump in Shadow Moon ever explained?

Tags: willow

So, with much trepidation, I picked up the sequel to *Willow*, *Shadow Moon* (co-written by George Lucas and Chris Claremont). I had heard that it took great liberties with the world created for the movie, and so far it definitely feels that way. Between the first and second chapter, twelve years apparently pass, cities are destroyed in a cataclysm, and Willow's name changes (although that one is at least slightly explained). Two more chapters in, and it still seems completely unexplained. Honestly, I'm not certain if I really plan on continuing reading, so I figured I would ask, are the events of the twelve year timeskip ever fully explained?

Comment: What's to explain? Nothing much of importance occurred between the two chapters and we're picking up where the action starts again.

Comment: The same could be said of Star Wars episodes 3 and 4...

Comment: Eh, it would be a little bit closer to if Episode 7 started with ten minutes of those celebratory end credits and then wiped over to "Twelve Years Later" with Luke lurching along, wartorn and weary of life as "Tharn Starkiller", with everyone making offhand references of "Man, it's a real shame that the Rebel Alliance was blown up. But let's talk about Spice prices."

Comment: Sounds like it was a cash-in?